# Automatic reposition of controls within groupbox

Tags: c#, vb.net

i am novice in **vb.net**. So, i have a lot of controls within groupbox.

In my program, while in run time, if i selected some value in combobox, another controls such as **textboxes get hidden**.

So, **while in run time** if one or two of the **controls gets hidden**, i want the **other controls get automatically repositioned** as well as the **border of the groupbox also gets to appropriate size**.
And,
If groupbox isnot the right control for these process, then please refer another advice and provide solutions too. Thank you..!

Comment: WinForms or WPF/XAML?

Comment: In addition to @DavidSdot question, what version of VS? Newer versions have something called a layout control that will do this for you. If you don't have that, I would suggest using docking and put each group of controls (Label-Textbox) into a panel and then hide the panel. This will make the next set of controls move into that position.

Comment: I have already solved it(By inserting flowlayoutpanel Within groupbox,then inserting list of panels within flowlayoutpanel , then inserting two controls within each panel.,.But anyway thanks for replying. I am using VS2013, WPF. 
Whenever, there is a question from me. I will first refer to you. Thanks.