# Searching Access records according to different conditions selected in a form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

In a WinForms application using VB.NET, I have already accessed three tables from MS Access and display the result in a DataGridView control.
Now, I am using three different conditions for searching access records as below:

1. Checkbox for PhoneNumber (if selected corresponding textbox will be enabled)
2. Checkbox for ItemName (if selected corresponding textbox will be enabled)
3. Three radio buttons for Year and Month and Day (if selected corresponding datetimepicker will be enabled)

Below these conditions, there is a Search button.

After one or two of above or combinations of above conditions are selected, value(s) entered, and Search button clicked, I want to display the results in the DataGridView.

The user can select first condition (PhoneNumber) only or second condition (ItemName) only or one of the radio buttons (Year/Month/Day) only or could choose multiple conditions and then only could go for Search button. So, there could be a number of choices for user to search.

Should I have to write code for every possible choices for accessing Access records (`Else If` statement) as below?

```
If chkPhoneNumber.checked= True Then
RunQuery("SELECT ...... WHERE txtPhoneNumber.Text = '...'")
Elseif chkItemName.checked= True Then
RunQuery("SELECT ...... WHERE txtItemName.Text = '...'")
Elseif chkPhoneNumber.Checked= True ANd chkItemName.checked= True Then
RunQuery("SELECT ...... WHERE txtPhoneNumber.Text = '..' And txtItemName.Text = '...'")
'Similar search for others too
Elseif rdbYear.checked= True Then
RunQuery("....")
Elseif rdbMonth.checked= True 
RunQuery("....")
Elseif rdbDay.checked= True 
RunQuery("....")
Elseif chkPhoneNumber.Checked= True ANd chkItemName.checked= True ANd rdbYear.checked= True 
RunQuery("....")
Elseif ....
Elseif ....
Elseif ....
Endif ....
```

In this way, there would be a lot of possible searching combinations.

I am kind of newer to this language. So, please present info in a simple way.

Comment: last year also you were new to this language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335616/automatic-reposition-of-controls-within-groupbox

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using If-ElseIf, You can do something like this

```
  Dim checkedControls As New List(Of Control)

    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is CheckBox AndAlso CType(Control, CheckBox).Checked Then
            checkedControls.Add(CType(Control, CheckBox))
        End If
    Next
```

Now you have all the checked controls, Just iterate over the list to create your query dynamically.

Comment: Sorry sir, i am not understanding it. Can you explain more please, for both about adding to list Class and about querying dynamically. And there is also a radiobutton control.Please help @prem

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to avoid building an SQL statement dynamically if possible (mostly because it allows SQL injection vulnerabilities and bugs). Instead, SQL parameters are best, and the query itself should be designed to apply each condition only if it has a valid (non-null/empty) parameter passed in. Partial example of such a query:

```sql
PARAMETERS ParPhoneNumber Text ( 10 ), ParItemName Text ( 255 );
SELECT …
FROM …
WHERE Nz([PhoneNumber]=[ParPhoneNumber], True) AND Nz([ItemName]=[ParItemName], True);
```

Null propagation means that that `[PhoneNumber]=[ParPhoneNumber]` condition will be null if either PhoneNumber itself or its corresponding search parameter are null*, then Nz makes sure null propagation stops at True. Similarly for the other conditions.

To pass the parameters, something like this should do the trick if you're using OleDb (untested):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ParPhoneNumber", IIf(chkPhoneNumber.Checked, txtPhoneNumber.Text, DBNull))
```

(Otherwise, look up however you pass parameters with whatever API you're using in .NET; that's kind of a separate issue.)

*If you want null values in the records to be excluded, use Nz on those first to come up with something that doesn't match anything (perhaps `Nz(Nz([PhoneNumber], "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")=[ParPhoneNumber], True)`). But it's best to make most values Required if at all possible; nulls in data are not particularly fun to deal with.